# Java Homework - Store counts to an array

Tags: java, arrays, store

I'm trying to write a program that will store the count of a random number into a single dimensional array. I'm getting stuck when assigning the number count to the array. This is a logic error and it compiles just fine. Thanks.

```
public class PP67 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int zero =0, one=0, two=0, three=0, four=0, five=0, six=0, seven=0, eight=0, nine=0;
        int[] counts = new int[10];//create array
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            int rand = (int)(Math.random()*10);     //generate 100 random ints between 0-9

            if (rand == 1){                    //assign the random number counter to the array
                one++;
                counts[0] = one;


            } else if (rand == 2) {
                two++;
                counts[1] = two;


            } else if (rand == 3) {
                three++;
                counts[2] = three;


            } else if (rand == 4) {
                four++;
                counts[3] = four;


            } else if (rand == 5) {
                five++;
                counts[4] = five;


            } else if (rand == 6) {
                six++;
                counts[5] = six;


            } else if (rand == 7) {
                seven++;
                counts[6] = seven;


            } else if (rand == 8) {
                eight++;
                counts[7] = eight;


            } else if (rand == 9) {
                nine++;
                counts[8] = nine;


            } else if (rand == 0) {
                zero++;
                counts[9] = zero;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The count for number 1 is: " + counts[0]); //need outside count loop
        System.out.println("The count for number 2 is: " + counts[1]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 3 is: " + counts[2]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 4 is: " + counts[3]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 5 is: " + counts[4]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 6 is: " + counts[5]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 7 is: " + counts[6]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 8 is: " + counts[7]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 9 is: " + counts[8]);
        System.out.println("The count for number 0 is: " + counts[9]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem you are having?

Comment: Try incrementing BEFORE you set it to the array.

Comment: The output shows 0 for each of the 10 array slots. It's not actually counting the random numbers for me. I need the program to count the number of times it comes up with the random number.

Comment: After incrementing beforehand and changing the rands precedence, I was able to get this running. Thanks all. @RUJordan n' Zou

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
int rand = (int)Math.random()*10;
```

The cast as a [higher precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than the multiplication.

Since `Math.random` returns a double in `[0, 1[` (as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) states), casting it to `int` after will always end up with a 0. So you're always doing `0 * 10`. Hence `rand` is always 0.

Multiply the random number by 10 first and then cast it to `int`.

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random()*10);
```

Also you could use the [`nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method from the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

```
Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(10); //will generate a random number in [0, 9]
```

Comment: For those who don't know, `[0, 1[` means "greater than or equal to zero and less than one." Some might be more used to `[0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to keep the same information both in variables one, two three etc and in the array counts.

2) The expression `int rand = (int)(Math.random()*10)`  always returns `0`. To generate random number in [0,9], it is better to use

```
Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(10);
```

3) You don't need all these `if-else if` conditions, you can use the random number as index of the array counts.

```
private final static int REP = 100;
private final static int MAX = 10;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int[] counts = new int[MAX];
    for(int i=0; i<REP; i++)
    {
        int n = rand.nextInt(MAX);
        counts[n]++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("The count for number %d is: %d \n", i, counts[i] );
    }
}
```